# Android - retrofit - how to sent string list with multiple values

Tags: java, android, retrofit

i've a problem to sent a BODY like:

```
{
    "items": [
        "one",
        "two"
    ],
    "repositiories": [
        {
            "repo1": "aaaa",
            "repo2": "bbbb",
            "repo3": "2020-12-09T11:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "deviceName": "AndroidPhone"
}
```

using the Retrofit.

I just make Two classes using the pojoSchema and did the function to sent the data:

```
    public sentItems(List<String> items, List<Position> repositories, String deviceName) {
        this.items= items;
        this.repositories= repositories;
        this.deviceName= deviceName;
    }
```

Also i updated my api interface with following code:

```
    @POST("/api/postItems/")
    Call<SentItemsAndRepos> sentItemsAndRepos(@Body SentItemsAndRepos SentItemsAndRepos);
```

And always when im trying to sent for example static values im getting the failure statement:

```
onFailure: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Just dont have any idea how to break it.. Im stucked with this case..
Maybe im sending wrong data but im not sure...
There is my example to sent:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add("one");
items.add("two");

Repositories firstRepo = new repositories("aaaa","bbbb",Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
List<Repositories> repositories = new ArrayList<repositories>();
repositories.add(firstRepo);

String deviceName = "AndroidPhone"
postItemsFunc(items,repositories,deviceName);

private void postItemsFunc(List<String> items, List<Position> repositories, String deviceName){

            SentItemsAndRepos sentItemsAndRepos= new SentItemsAndRepos(items,repositories,deviceName);
            Call<SentItemsAndRepos> call = ApiLoginInterface.sentItemsAndRepos(sentItemsAndRepos);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<SentItemsAndRepos>() {
```

This is anything i think you want to help, ofc if you want to help.. :)
I will be very greateful to take your time to help me...

Answer (score 0):

I am implementing some source code from my git repository

```
public void fetchContact(String type, String key){

    apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<List<Contact>> call = apiInterface.getContact(type, key);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Contact>> call, Response<List<Contact>> response) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            contacts = response.body();
            adapter = new Adapter(contacts, MainActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Contact>> call, Throwable t) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error\n"+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Visit the following link to understand it easily

`https://github.com/Istiakshovon/RetrofitRecyclerView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/istiak/getdatabyretrofit/MainActivity.java`

Comment: Hello, i think it's close to my problem but your solution doesn't solving this..

Comment: @3milBow Ow! Sorry. I didn't read your whole question. You are having issue on `onFailure: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $`
For me, this shows error while you are having issue in `php(server file)`
So, can you implement `server` script?

Comment: I think i don't understand your question :P This code comes from Android Studio, not at all from web services.